# Link within email that opens a dialog

Tags: email, sharepoint, popup, outlook, workflow

Ok, I have a client with a peculiar request. He wants to receive an (generated by a workflow) email with a hyperlink that will open a pop-up dialog if you click on it. Note: the link within the email should open a popup and not a web page in a browser.

I immediately thought this would be impossible, but after looking around a bit I found out that you can create a workflow variable with tags in them and insert them into the email body.

eg: `<a href="some_page.asp">here</a>`

The conclusion that I draw from this is that an email consists of html code that the email client renders. Now I'm wondering if there is a way to make use of a tag no cause a modal dialog to pop up?

I guess the question is what functionality the email client (Microsoft Outlook) supports. I can't figure how to attach some JavaScript or something that will be used by Outlook. Is there perhaps some embedded functionality within Outlook to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

That is very easy. Use this sample code and understand how it works with just normal "mailto" function:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>
This is an email link:
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello%20again">
Send Mail</a>
</p>

<p>

</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I do not want a link on a page that sends an email. I want a link in the email body that opens a dialog with some information.

Comment: okei okei... yu r sending html codes that can be rendered by the email client?

Comment: Yes. Though, I'm not sure exactly how comprehensive the email client renderer is.

Comment: you can never be sure of that mate :P

for wht joy your client needs a dialog box btw?

Comment: A person fills in an InfoPath form on a SharePoint site wherein he nominates someone for a coupon or a voucher of some kind. I'm not exactly sure on the details. The person receiving the nomination gets an email notifying him of the nomination. The email should also have a link that displays some information about the voucher or whatever he's nominated for. The client is quite adamant that he wants this in a popup dialog type of box.

Answer (score 1):

use

window.open('example.html',400,600) ​;

in your HTML code..

Also Refer this link for the answer of your question

> http://www.coderanch.com/t/121512/HTML-CSS-JavaScript/Opening-popup-JS-outlook-mails

Comment: The problem is that almost all modern mail clients seem to block any JavaScript included in the mail.